# How do you delete a ractivejs object

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I know in vanilla JS you can just use the delete command to remove an object but I can't find anything in the docs for object manipulation.

For example how would I delete this object in ractivejs?

```
template.set('object', {hello: 'world', bye: 'world'});
```

I want to later on delete the `bye` object from that 'object'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the template's perspective, it usually doesn't matter if you just set the value to `undefined`:

```
template.set( 'object.bye' );
```

Unless you're using it in a hash, then you can delete the key and call update:

```
delete template.get( 'object').bye;
template.update( 'object.bye' );
```

It's currently a requested feature (https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1649) to add an `unset` method:

```
template.unset( 'object.bye' );
```

If you look in the comments on that issue, there's a `Ractive.prototype.unset` polyfill you can use.